# replace preg_replace bbcode to html

Tags: php, preg-replace

help, im trying to convert bbcode to html code , and i keep getting this error

the bbcode is `[url=link][attach]1[/attach][/url]`

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for( ! ) Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/'

        $content = $getThread['message'];
        $bbUrl = '/\[url=(http|https|ftp)://{1}([a-zA-Z0-9/%@?:#&+._=-]*)\](.*?)\[/url\]/gixsm';
        $htmlUrl = '<a href="{$1}://{$2}" target="_blank">{$3}</a>';
        $atable = $thread->get_atable($tid);
        $content = preg_replace($bbUrl, $htmlUrl, $content);
```

after the url done, will convert the [attach]1[/attach] again by using

```
$bbAttachment = 'etc...';
$htmlAttachment = 'etc...';
$content = preg_replace($bbAttachment, $htmlAttachment , $content);
```

Is this the correct way to do?

Appreciate for helping.

Comment: You need to escape foreslashes `/` with backslashes when using a foreslash as the pattern delimiter so they read `\/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your Regex. You need proper escaping for '/' character.

change this

```
 $bbUrl = '/\[url=(http|https|ftp)://{1}([a-zA-Z0-9/%@?:#&+._=-]*)\](.*?)\[/url\]/gixsm';
```

to this

```
 $bbUrl = '/\[url=(http|https|ftp):\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\/%@?:#&+._=-]+)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/gixsm';
```

You should also change `*` to `+` because I assume you don't want to parse urls that may be empty.

Comment: Better, i think, would be to pick a different delimiter.  Past a certain point it's just easier.